# kaa monogodb in authentication mode

Tags: mongodb, kaa

kaa-node throws following ERROR in the log file:

```
    Command failed with error 13: 'not authorized on kaa
 to execute command { createIndexes: "endpoint_registration",
```

1. user "mongokaa" creadted in db kaa, role = dbOwner

   ```
   db.getUsers()    [
       {
               "_id" : "kaa.mongokaa",
               "user" : "mongokaa",
               "db" : "kaa",
               "roles" : [
                       {
                               "role" : "dbOwner",
                               "db" : "kaa"
                       }
               ]
       }]
   ```

   2. mongodb started with
      `mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf`
   3. athentication credentials are set on the Log appender configuration page

Why kaa-node kan't execute the command "createIndexes"?

The command can be executed over mongodb shell when I'm logged in with the user "mongokaa".

- mongodb version: 3.2
- ubuntu version: 16.0.4 LTS
- kaa-node version: 0.10.0

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why did you create a new user in mongo? Did you enable auth in db?

Comment: Yes I've enabled auth in mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Kaa is not supported MongoDB version 3.2. See [Kaa requirements and supported versions](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/latest/Administration-guide/System-installation/Single-node-installation/#kaa-requirements-and-supported-versions) in our pre-release documentation. You can try MongoDB 2.6.9 version.

Comment: Kaa is running with MongoDB version 3.2 whithout any problems when the  authentication is disabled.

Comment: In the installation instructions you write to install MongoDB 3.2 : see it here Install MongoDB (Optional, you may install Cassandra 3.5 instead) (source).
If you have installed previous version, this is how you can completely uninstall it:
$ sudo dpkg -l | grep mongo
$ sudo apt-get remove mongodb* --purge
Add the MongoDB repository to the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list.
$ sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
$ echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list

Comment: I've found where the problem is:

Comment: MongoDB supports the following authentication mechanisms:
SCRAM-SHA-1
MongoDB Challenge and Response (MONGODB-CR)
Changed in version 3.0: New challenge-response users created in 3.0 will use SCRAM-SHA-1. If using 2.6 user data, MongoDB 3.0 will continue to use the MONGODB-CR. Kaa is using the MONGODB-CR see source:`for (MongoDBCredential credential : configuration.getMongoCredentials()) {
                credentials.add(MongoCredential.createMongoCRCredential(credential.getUser(), configuration.getDbName(), 
                        credential.getPassword().toCharArray()));
            }`

Comment: Thank you for reporting. We will fix the documentation for MongoDB installation on Ubuntu 16.04.
Also, you can modify existing MongoDB log appender to support MongoDB 3 versions. Refer to our custom log appender documentation http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Customization-guide/Customizable-system-components/Log-appenders/ for details.